# How do I open a tun device created with 'ip tuntap'

Tags: java, linux, networking

I'm trying open a TUN device in a Linux (hopefully ultimately in a Java application). Since I don't want to use any native code (I want to avoid JNI if possible) I want to do as much as possible through the commandline. Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Create a TUN interface using `ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun`
- Set it to up, and give it an IP address (simple enough with the `ip` command)
- Open some kind of `/dev/tun0` file to write traffic from the network side.

The last step is where I'm a little confused - I gather this would work on Unix because network adapters are files, but I'm on Linux and I don't think I can access NICs that way. I understand this is simple with native code (make a few calls to `ioctl` and get a file descriptor) but unless there's some way to do that from the commandline it won't work.

Is there any way I can open an already configured `tun` interface (configured with `ip tuntap`) with an `open` call, and start writing network-side IP packets to it (without using `ioctl`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've set it up via `ip tuntap`, then you can just open it as a read/write file form java and then write whole ethernet packets to it. You can open it twice (FileInputStream/FileOutputStream) to read and write ethernet packets to it.

Comment: How do I open it though? `new FileInputStream("/dev/net/tun0")` will (presumably) return File Not Found (I've only checked with `ls` though)

Comment: Ah, indeed - sorry, just read up on TUN and it doesn't create an actual device file. You will need to write some C code, unfortunately. If you don't want to write JNI code, you could create a program that opens the device and bridges the new file descriptor with its STDIN/STDOUT; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336157/running-external-program-with-redirected-stdin-and-stdout-from-java on how to interface this with Java.

Comment: You're right - I didn't read [this](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) properly, it turns out your process still has to open the interface with some ioctl calls even after you've set it up with `ip tuntap`. Looks like I'll have to man up and learn JNI :)