# is there a way to know whether tun/tap interface is opened?

Tags: c, linux, tun

I am making an application using tun interface tun0. I have been successfully able to send and receive packets through the interface. Is there any way to know when the tun interface is opened  as in `ifconfig tun0 up`?

I want do some part of my underlying device initialization only when the interface is active.
(added later) 
I am following the examples from http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101919/how-do-i-open-a-tun-device-created-with-ip-tuntap

Comment: its not a duplicate. one way i thought of is that we can know that interface has been opened(using `ifconfig` or `ip link set`) is when the first packet is read.