# Executing an EXE from Java and getting input and output from EXE

Tags: java

I have an ***EXE*** file, `addOne.exe` which continuously gets an integer input from the user on the console **(NOT command line parameters)** and outputs the *integer +  1* onto the console . Sample output is shown below:

```
1
2

6
7

29
30
...
```

I am trying to code a java program that can:

- **Run** the EXE
- Continuously get **user input** from the **Java program** using `Scanner.nextInt()` and input to the EXE as console input
- Whenever the EXE outputs text to the console, print that text from the **Java program**

I am able to run the EXE using:

```
new ProcessBuilder("D:\\pathtofile\\addOne.exe").start();
```

but I don't know how to send input from the Java program to the EXE and get output from the EXE to the Java program.

Thank you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573457/java-processbuilder-input-output-stream?s=2|3.2312 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905193/java-use-input-and-outputstream-of-processbuilder-continuously

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you start an external program with `ProcessBuilder` with `ProcessBuilder#start()`, a `Process` object will be created for the program and as follows:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\pathtofile\\addOne.exe").start();
```

You can access the input stream and output stream with the `process` object:

```
InputStream processInputStream = process.geInputStream();
OutputSteam processOutputStream = process.getOutputStream();
```

To write data into the external program, you can instantiate a `BufferedWriter` with the `processOutputSream`:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(processOutputStream));
```

To read data from the external program, you can instantiate a `BufferedReader` with the `processInputStream`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processInputStream));
```

Now you have all the components to reach your goal:

1. Read the user input from console with `Scanner#nextInt()`.
2. Write the user input to the external program with `writer`
3. Read the data output from the external program with `reader`
4. Finally print the data to the console with `System.out.println()`

Comment: Could you elaborate on 2 and 3? How to write the user input to the external program with `writer`?  Say I have a simple python program which has 3 lines. `print("Waiting for user input"); result = input(); print(result)`(not valid). How can I use `write` to serve `input()`?

Comment: My question was solved: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62234919/10315163