# Capturing output of exe while process is yet not completed

Tags: java, exe, processbuilder

I am working with one cmd like executable and source code of that is not available.

Executable is having multiple command sequence to be entered before it exit. Each command takes random time from 1 sec to 1 min.

I tried with Java's `Process builder` and `runtime` but I am getting output only after program completely exits from execution. Also, I am not able to insert any command to that executable via `BufferedWriter`. So my question is how to get output of executable while it is still running

Quenstions referred: [Executing an EXE from Java and getting input and output from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067918/executing-an-exe-from-java-and-getting-input-and-output-from-exe)

[java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program) etc.

Comment: That is probably because the `exe` doesn't write data to the output stream line by line. You'll have to read data from the process as it is available instead of reading it line by line. You can do that using an `InputStream` instead of a `BufferedReader`.