# Sending String trough cmd pipe to exe file

Tags: java, cmd, pipe

I have an exe file, which I can run from cmd like this:

```
echo text|majka.exe -f majka.w-lt  //or...
majka.exe -f majka.w-lt < text.txt  //same, but reading text from file
```

I want to send this command from java. I know I can use ProcessBuilder like this:

```
String text = "text";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\majkawin\\majka.exe", "-f", "majka.w-lt");
pb.start();
```

but I don't know how to send String text by pipe to this command. I prefer solution without creating text.txt file if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pb.start()` returns a `Process`, which has input and output streams, which you can read from and write to.

This is all documented.

Comment: Thanks for your RTFM answer, but can you give me an example? I looked on Process class before, but there is only getInput/Output/ErrorStream method. How you can use it after Process is started?

Comment: TBF @Pivoman, had you put in your question, 'I've looked at Process class before, but there are only getInput/Output/ErrorStream methods. How you can use it after Process is started?' You would have been less likely to receive a RTFM type answer!

Comment: @Compo If I should write there my whole days research, someone could use another fancy shortcut "TL;DR". :D Anyway, I admit, that I'm not a master of cmd and I found, that I can use in cmd only majka.exe -f majka.w-lt (without pipe) and write inputs there. So this answer was eventually little helpful and I will accept it. Better answer I finally found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38068513/3125587